# What is the correct term for an operation that forks a list (functional programming)?

Tags: functional-programming

Consider the problem where you have a list which needs to be split into multiple lists (buckets) given a function given an element and returning the index of the destination list (bucket).  The output of the operation is a list of lists.

What's the correct name for this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One name would be grouping: the Scala function that does this is `groupBy` (though it returns a Map from discriminator keys to Lists instead of the list of lists you're asking for).

Comment: You're right, this is grouping. Thanks.  I got myself turned around by thinking it was related to zip.

Answer (score 3):

You can also call it `partition`.

Answer (score 1):

If your list is ordered and the function in question splits into multiple buckets of roughly equal size (for some notion of size), then it could be called *quantiling*.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually helpful in a different way, so please accept the upvote.